# Proving Multiplication on the Set of Integers is Well-defined

Tags: integers

I'm using following definitions: On the set $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ we define an equivalence relation $\sim$ for all $(a,b)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ and $(c,d)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$ as
\begin{align*}\tag{I}
(a,b)\sim (c,d):\Leftrightarrow a+d=b+c
\end{align*}
The set of integers $\mathbb{Z}$ is then defined as
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{Z}:=\{[(a,b)]_{\sim}\mid (a,b)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\},
\end{align*}
where $[(a,b)]_{\sim}$ denotes the equivalence class of $(a,b)$, which is defined as
\begin{align*}\tag{II}
[(a,b)]_{\sim}=\{(c,d)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}\mid (a,b)\sim (c,d)\}.
\end{align*}

For convenience I will write $[(a,b)]$ instead of $[(a,b)]_{\sim}$.

Addition $+$ and multiplication $\cdot$ on the set $\mathbb{Z}$ are defined as
\begin{align*}\tag{III}
[(a,b)]+[(c,d)]:=[(a+c,b+d)]
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}\tag{IV}
[(a,b)]\cdot [(c,d)]:=[(ac+bd,ad+bc)].
\end{align*}

I've already proved that addition on $\mathbb{Z}$ is well-defined. However, I'm struggling to do the same for multiplication.

Let
\begin{align*}
[(a,b)]&=[(x,y)]
\\
[(c,d)]&=[(z,w)].
\end{align*}

Then we have
\begin{align*}\tag{Va}
(a,b)\sim(x,y)&:\Leftrightarrow a+y=b+x
\\
\tag{Vb}
(c,d)\sim(z,w)&:\Leftrightarrow c+w=d+z.
\end{align*}

We have to show that
\begin{align*}
[(a,b)]\cdot [(c,d)]=[(x,y)]\cdot [(z,w)]
\end{align*}
holds. Using $(IV)$ this turns into
\begin{align*}
[(ac+bd,ad+bc)]=[(xz+yw,xw+yz)]
\end{align*}
and by $(II)$ we then have
\begin{align*}
(ac+bd,ad+bc)\sim (xz+yw,xw+yz)
\end{align*}
Using $(I)$ this is equivalent to
\begin{align*}\tag{VI}
(ac+bd)+(xw+yz)=(ad+bc)+(xz+yw).
\end{align*}

So I have to find a way to get from equations $(Va)$ and $(Vb)$ to $(VI)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember, $x+y=x'+y$ is equivalent to $x=x'$ for natural numbers $x$, $x'\!$, and $y$. Thus, we have:
\begin{align*}
(ac+bd)+(xw+yz)&=(ad+bc)+(xz+yw)\\
\iff(ac+bd)+(xw+yz)+aw&=(ad+bc)+(xz+yw)+aw\\
\iff (ad+bd)+(xw+yz)+az&=(ad+bc)+(xz+bw)+xw\\
\iff bd+yz+az&=bc+xz+bw\\
\iff bd+xz+bz&=bd+xz+bz.
\end{align*}

---

Here, the equivalences are:

1. Adding $aw$.
2. LHS: (Va) and distributivity, which gives $ac+aw=ad+az$. RHS: (Vb) and distributivity, which gives $aw+yw=bw+xw$.
3. Cancelling $ad$ and $xw$.
4. LHS: (Va) and distributy, which gives $az+yz=bz+xz$. RHS: (Vb) and distributivity, which gives $bc+bw=bd+bz$.

Comment: How could you possibly come up with this acrobatic act? Anyways, the important thing is, it actually works out just fine, thanks.

Comment: Another approach is to fix $(a,b)$ and let $(c,d)\sim(z,w)$, then prove $[(a,b)]\cdot[(c,d)]=[(a,b)]\cdot[(z,w)]$. Then, do the same thing for the LHS. (i.e., just let each component vary individually.) This simplifies all the calculations.

Comment: You mean prove $[(a,b)]\cdot[(c,d)]=[(a,b)]\cdot[(z,w)]$ and then $[(a,b)]\cdot[(z,w)]=[(x,y)]\cdot[(z,w)]$?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. (You could also start by observing that this multiplication operation commutes, so you only need to check one of those identities.)

Comment: sounds interesting.. and hopefully a bit more straightforward. Will definitely try to work this idea out.